# external list sharepoint javascript

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, external

Hi I need to use external list from SP, and I need something like this, with javascript or any other code

DataBase

```
Name ID Value Value2 Value3

Nam1 01 00000 000000 000000

Nam2 02 11111 111111 111111

Nam3 03 22222 222222 222222
```

then in my external list I would like to filter by name, so I select Nam1

```
Description Value

Value      00000

Value2     000000

Value3     000000

ID         01
```

if I select Nam2 it would be

```
Description Value

Value       11111

Value2      111111

Value3      111111

ID          02
```

Is there anyway to do that??

Hope you can understand my question, English is no my native language

Comment: *Is there anyway to do that??* - Yes, but this is such a broad question. You have to narrow it down to at least a certain direction so that people can help you.

Comment: I'll connect that external list to a Visio, and because Visio web service doesn't allow me to edit the shapes data, i'm stuck in the same list. What I need to do, is, whenever a user open the Visio page, the shape must have his information. So I was thinking on external data, because with javascript I can edit lists, so maybe I can edit what I explained before.

Comment: Do you know any website or blog with that kind of information? Im googleing it but I can't find any information, could you guide me a bit??